# PhpStorm change Project Files font

Tags: fonts, settings, phpstorm

(using PhpStorm v6.0, the last one)

In Settings `Editor > Colors & Fonts > Font` one can easily change the font of the code being displayed right side of the editor.

But I don't see in the Settings a way to change the font (size) of the left part of the editor - named "Project Files" that has the list of the files that belong to the project.

I want to increase the font size on my laptop so that the list of files appears more clearly.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Quite likely that fonts in Project View font will be fixed size (hardcoded). But you can check that: **Settings | Appearance -> Override default fonts**

Comment: See also http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69802.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This screencast shows how to solve this issue:

http://www.screenr.com/ozY7

On mac:
**PhpStorm -> Preferences ->  Appearance -> Override default fonts**

I also tested this successfully with PyCharm, so it probably works for IntelliJ IDEA, RubyMine and other JetBrains tools.

Comment: Note that if your "menu font" changed after a Java upgrade (in my case Java 7) I had to choose the `Ubuntu Light` font instead of `Ubuntu`.